# Power factor and Harmonics associated with Electric Vehicle charging

Tags: battery-charging, power-electronics, converter, power-factor-correction, harmonics

What is the power factor associated with (typical) DC fast chargers and onboard chargers in electrical vehicles? Also, how much is the harmonic content (especially triple-N harmonics) associated with these chargers? I actually want to understand the neutral sizing for a (purely) EV load and hence it would be helpful if somebody could also shed some light on any other related topic which I should consider for my study.

[image]
Image Source:http://inpel.ulsan.ac.kr/battery-charger-technologies-for-electric-vehicle/

Comment: So, first question transformer based or switched mode?

Comment: To be honest, I do not know much about the different types of converters and usage in EVs. So can you please give an answer considering my ignorance about the converter type being transformer based or switched-mode...

Comment: It totally depends on the charger design, but on any site large enough to matter I would expect there to be a delta-star transformer somewhere in the vicinity of the chargers, in which case triplen just inpacts the K rating of the transformer because it just produces circulating current in the delta winding. Only the commercial three phase chargers are really big enough to be interesting for this and I would expect them to borrow heavily from the motor drives industry when it comes to harmonic suppression (And really everything else).

Comment: Would a 3 phase charger present a blanced load and therefore very little or zero neutral current? Perhaps you should do some research.

Comment: As you show in your diagram there is a Power Factor Correction stage so the PF is nominally 1. The same applies to DC fast chargers not mounted in the vehicle.

Comment: @SolarMike Note that a balanced load does not automatically mean zero neutral current! Do the sums for a load consisting of all third harmonic, you will find that the neutral current actually exceeds the phase current! The op is clearly aware of this issue, but I doubt that it is a big deal with modern switched mode chargers, old school 6 pulse plus inductor stuff might be a different matter.

Comment: @DanMills aren’t you meant to design to avoid harmonics ... at least that was what our prof started out with...

Comment: @SolarMike Well, yes but it don't always pan out like that. For example old school phase angle controls used for things like stage lighting dimmers are a notorious source of harmonics, but the simplicity, robustness and low cost still favours thyristor dimming over IGBT based high frequency choppers for many applications. A large thyristor dimmer install plus an over sized delta-star transformer is cheaper and more reliable then the HF switcher based stuff.

Comment: @DanMills So the god profit wins out again...

Comment: @SolarMike All engineering is that art of the compromise, and 'Best' usually involves cost considerations as well as purely technical ones. Further the reliability issue is very real, big iron in the basement as triplen suppression will last 50 years or so without significant maintenance, and will survive 100% short term (As in tens of minutes) overloads, cannot say that for a typical IGBT chopper in real use.

Comment: @KevinWhite I am talking about the harmonics which would lead to poor 'true power factor'.